# Django render nested templates to pdf

Tags: python, html, css, django, pdf

I'm trying to convert html to pdf on my website, using Django.
I tried to use wkhtmltopdf and pisa (and some django modules that use them), but I always have the same problem with css and static files.

I have a base layout that looks like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
        {% block css %}
            {% bootstrap_css %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'website/css/style.css' %}" />
        {% endblock css %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
        <div class="container" id="main-container">
            <div id="page-content">{% block content %}{% endblock content %}</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Another layout that extends the base layout and include my résumé:

```
{% extends "website/base.html" %}
<!-- ... -->
{% block content %}
    <!-- ... -->
    {% include "website/cv.html" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

And my résumé:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'website/css/cv.css'  %}" />
<div id="cv">
    <!-- ... -->
    <img src="{% static 'website/img/me.jpg' %}" class="img-rounded">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

I want to render my résumé to pdf, the problem is that it uses bootstrap_css ans static files (a css file and a picture) and they are not rendered.

I checked some similar topics but they put all the css in the html, which is not really good in my situation. And even if I try this solution by putting all the css in my résumé, the {% bootstrap_css %} block does not work.

Is there any way to make it work? I can use any library/module that works with django or linux.

Thanks

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I wonder if anyone has a better answer now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be surprised if you could find a 100% mapping between `HTML` and `PDF`! Especially with fancy "newish" things like bootstrap. (It's hard enough to convert between word-processor formats!)

But, what if you had a special in-line `CSS` script that was only used for the `PDF` rendering? Could you use the `mediatype` attribute to control it? I wonder...

Disclaimer: I *never* convinced Django to do what I wanted. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to put all the css (bootstrap and my own css) directly  in the <style></style> tag, and pass it directly to the wkhtmltopdf binary. It works pretty well, except for the bootstrap grid system.
I think I can do something that looks like bootstrap grid for my purpose using the print mediatype (wkhtmltopdf can handle it), but as I can't use Django templates tags I have to duplicate all my css for the pdf rendering, and I don't really like this idea.

Comment: Django isn't really for perfectionists -- "It's for perfectionists with deadlines" :-) At least, that was my impression in 2011.